# Linux command "systemctl status" is not working inside a Docker container

Tags: centos, systemd, docker

The command `systemctl status` is not working. It never has. My container is on CentOS 7. When I issue `systemctl status` I get results `Failed to get D-Bus connection: operation not permitted.`

#### Regression

1. I then looked into upgrading systemd. I removed the `/etc/yum/protected.d/system.conf` file. I then used `yum remove systemd`. I see that systemd version 219-19.el7_2.4 has been installed. I choose `N` to not actually remove systemd. I then installed systemd-libs-219-19.el7_2.7.x86_64.rpm. I then installed systemd version 2.7. I then used `yum remove systemd` just to determine the version. I see that systemd version 219-19.el7_2.7 is installed. I choose `NO` to abort the removal. systemctl status still does not work. I get the same error: `Failed to get D-Bus connection: operation not permitted.`
2. I tried creating a new Docker container with the `-privileged` flag. When I used the `-p 80:80` option, the Docker run command failed.
3. When I left out the `-p 80:80` option in my `docker run` command, the new container had the same problem.
4. I created a Docker container with a `docker run ... -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro`" option. I had the same problem.

I expect `systemctl status` to work inside a Docker container.

What should I do to get `systemctl status` to work in a Docker container?

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to fix this issue in a CentOS:7 Docker container.
I've followed mainly [the Guide on CentOS Docker image project](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/centos#systemd-integration).

```
FROM centos:7

ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

# Install anything. The service you want to start must be a SystemD service.

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

Now, build the image, and run it using at least the following arguments to `docker run` command: `-v /run -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro`

Then main point is that `/usr/sbin/init` must be the first process inside the Docker container.

So if you want to use a custom script that executes some commands before running `/usr/sbin/init`, launch it at the end of your script using `exec /usr/sbin/init` (in a bash script).

Here is an example:

```
ADD cmd.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cmd.sh

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/cmd.sh"]
```

And here is the content of `cmd.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Do some stuffs

exec /usr/sbin/init # To correctly start D-Bus thanks to https://forums.docker.com/t/any-simple-and-safe-way-to-start-services-on-centos7-systemd/5695/8
```

You could have `System is booting up. See pam_nologin(8)` if your using the PAM system, in that case, delete `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/systemd-nologin.conf` in your `Dockerfile` because it creates the file `/var/run/nologin` which generates this specific error.

Answer (score 0):

Run the docker as following, It's works for me,

```
docker run -it --privileged -p 10081:80 centos7 /bin/bash
```