# Unable to start ssh service on Centos Docker image

Tags: centos, docker

I downloaded the `centos 7` docker image from docker hub. When I try to enable sshd on the server, it does not allow me to enable ssh service.

Below are the steps to replicate my issue:

```
docker pull centos
docker run -i -d --name testSSH centos /bin/bash
docker exec -it testSSH /bin/bash
```

Once inside the centos box, I executed the following commands:

```
yum install openssh-server
ssh-keygen 
ssh-keygen -t rsa
yum install -y initscripts
service start sshd
service sshd start
```

I get this error message now:

```
[root@f9e4d1efcfd9 /]# service sshd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start sshd.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

I have used physical centos machines, and the same command works perfectly.

Comment: You'll probably need to activate systemd, as per the instructions under the 'Systemd integration' heading: https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/

Comment: I will be really glad if down-voters kindly explain why they down-voted a question.

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel I followed the steps as mentioned in the link you provided. I referred to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276340/linux-command-systemctl-status-is-not-working-inside-a-docker-container , but I have the same error.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some information about what you're trying to accomplish? Docker is something of a process isolation framework, and sshd doesn't really fit into that paradigm.

Comment: I need to install a machine that contains greenplum database and my application on the same machine. The installation for database needs `ssh localhost` to work. I am  trying to activate sshd for that. My laptop is a ubuntu 16.04 machine

Comment: The reason to choose docker is to keep the application and DB together as a deployment ready image

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Greenplum DB, so I did some digging. You can install it in two ways: either by compiling from source, or by installing the binary on Ubuntu. Here are some details on those two approaches: [from source with Docker](https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/docker-gpdb/), [Ubuntu](https://greenplum.org/install-greenplum-oss-on-ubuntu/). You can try the Ubuntu route by pulling down an Ubuntu image instead of the CentOS one.

Comment: Thanks @Haxiel. The link you shared  https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/ fixed it. I had to add an extra param for adapting to ubuntu. If you can write that in the answer, I could accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87457/discussion-between-haxiel-and-tammy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current official Docker image for CentOS does contain `systemd`, but it is inactive by default. This is documented at the [Docker Hub page for the CentOS image](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/).

> Systemd is now included in both the centos:7 and centos:latest base
>   containers, but it is not active by default. In order to use systemd,
>   you will need to include text similar to the example Dockerfile below:

The sample Dockerfile provided is as follows:

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

By removing these files, `systemd` is prevented from starting several services during container startup. This approach results in a bare-bones, yet functional `systemd` inside the container.

Running a container from this image also requires a specific option to mount the `cgroup` volume:

```
$ docker run -it -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro systemd-app
```

The `-v` option bind mounts the `/sys/fs/cgroup` directory from the host to the container in a read-only fashion.

It is also noted that on Ubuntu hosts, an additional option may be required for the container to work correctly:

```
$ docker run -it -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -v /tmp/$(mktemp -d):/run systemd-app
```

---

Note: Most of this material, including the Dockerfile itself, appear to be taken from this blog post by Daniel Walsh: [Running systemd within a Docker Container](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/).